# Generic Language Collation for MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, collation

We need a collation or a way that covers multiple language.

For example turkish language has different letters such as Ğ,Ş 
german has different letters like ä,, french has different, polish-swedish have different..

Well and when we write a query we dont know that the word's language charset, can be turkish, can be polish etc.

I saw some examples, you can set collation but if you dont know which will be used then how you can make it generic.

Comment: Use `nvarchar` and you can support any *characters* you need to. After that, collation only really dictates *sorting* conventions, which of course you cannot fail to get somewhat wrong when you're sorting a mixture of languages, since their sorting conventions may differ.

Comment: The other problem is that the db is not belongs to us and we cannot change how we want..

Comment: `nvarchar` is the way. If you can't change it then you're out of luck I guess.